# htaccess rewriterule query to url

Tags: .htaccess, get, query-string

I am trying to make this:

```
http://www.testsite.com/bacon
```

be this

```
http://www.testsite.com/index.php?food=bacon
```

so the user types in/clicks on a link that is `http://www.testsite.com/bacon` but the server interprets it as `http://www.testsite.com/index.php?food=bacon`.

Some explanation to any solutions would be valuable too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `.htaccess` file to make a vanity URL for your task

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f  
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} &gt;""
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ index.php?food=$1
```

**Explanation**

1. Our first line turns on the rewrite engine.
2. The line above checks to see if the request is a file
3. This line turns adds the .php extension. So for example if you URL is /friends, the friends.php file would be called.(So this part is optional according to your use case)
4. The final two lines pick up the url when it is not a file name, for example, your-url.com/philipbrown and routes it to profile.php?user=philipbrown.

Visit [this link](http://culttt.com/2011/11/16/how-to-make-vanity-urls-using-php-htaccess-and-mysql/) for more information

Comment: Not working for me. The site says that http://www.testsite.com/test directs to the correct test.php file. However what I want is for the index.php to load the variable. so http://www.testsite.com/helloworld would equal http://www.testsite.com/index.php?type=helloworld

Comment: @BITmixit which part?

Comment: ammended comment. Essentially the two first lines work perfectly but aren't really needed for my purpose. The last 2 just plain old don't work.

Comment: @BITmixit: Try using this code if it works I'll update the answer
`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?food=$1`

Comment: Deleted the answer. The RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ index.php?type=$1 [L] works perfectly but I didn't need the rest of the APACHE code. Is it needed for my kind of project as it's a simple site that will literally just have a index.php file. Thanks and apologies for the mistake (I'm dyslexic and dyspraxic)

Comment: @BITmixit: no problem mate, and I am glad to help. I'll leave the additional code int the answer so that anybody visiting in the future will too have the choice to use it if he requires it. :)